# Kivy: ScrollViewApp example in Kivy Language

Tags: python, kivy

I'm having trouble with going back and forth between the concepts in the Kivy language, vs. Python language. I'm not very good at explaining things, and i've thought about how to explain my *specific* problem, but the best way i can think to do that is:

How would one implement the [`ScrollViewApp`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/scrollview.py) using the `Builder` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hm, something like

```
ScrollView:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 500, 320
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_scroll_x: False

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

        ScrollButton:
            text: '1'
        ScrollButton:
            text: '2'
        ScrollButton:
            text: '3'
        ScrollButton:
            text: '4'
        ScrollButton:
            text: '5'
        ScrollButton:
            text: '6'

<ScrollButton@Button>
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 480, 40
```

here, however we don't really have a way to dynamically create the children (well, there would be ways, but they are ugly), so i put a few manualy, idealy you would create the ScrollView and GridLayout in kv, and then put the children inside from python (using ids, as explained in the doc).

edit: more complete version using an app and ObjectProperty

kv file (scroll.kv):

```
ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        ScrollView:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 500, 320
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                padding: 10
                spacing: 10
                height: self.minimum_height
                size_hint: None, None
                do_scroll_x: False
                id: container

<ScrollButton>
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 480, 40
```

python file (main.py):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class ScrollButton(Button):
    pass

class ScrollApp(App):
    def build(self):
        super(ScrollApp, self).build()
        container = self.root.ids.container
        for i in range(30):
            container.add_widget(ScrollButton(text=str(i)))
        return self.root   # return root does not work

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScrollApp().run()
```

Comment: And there you see the problem. My "ScrollViewApp" would be one of the screens in my ScreenManager. I thought to append the Buttons to the scroller dynamically using an ObjectProperty as a reference, but no dice. Is there really no equivalent method?

Comment: To give you a bit of background, it's a To-Do List app. The buttons would be the tasks called from a stored table.

Comment: Edited to show a more complete app that should get you on tracks.

Comment: This seems to have created more problems, but you did answer my question. Thank you, @tshirtman.

Comment: What problems? i only quickly ran the app, but it displayed fine, no crash.

Comment: No need to do `root.ids.['container']()` you can just do `root.ids.container` instead.